# Why is my React view not updating when the redux store changes?

Tags: react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux. I've been trying to create a counter to learn how to work with Redux, but I cannot get the view to update, or mapStateToProps to be called. I've gone over the Redux troubleshooting page, and looked at a number of similar threads posted here. Could somebody please help me identify what is wrong with this code?

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

import './index.scss';

let Counter = props => {
    console.log('>>> counter', props)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>counter (Redux Version)</h1>
            <p>count: {props.count}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

let increment = () => {
    return {
        type: 'INC'
    }
}

const counterReducer = (state = {count: 0}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INC':
            console.log('>>> inc');
            return { count: state.count + 1 };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('>>> map state to props', state);
    return { count: state.counterReducer.count };
};

const store = createStore(counterReducer);
connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Counter);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Counter count={0}/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

window.store = store;
window.increment = increment;
```

Using the Chrome console, I am able to see the sate of the store, and then dispatch the increment event. When I do this, I see that the state in the store has updated correctly but the value shown in the paragraph tag still says 0.

```
store.getState()
  {count: 0}

store.dispatch(increment());
  VM1382:1 >>> inc
  {type: "INC"}

store.getState()
  {count: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` isn't updating on dispatch because `Counter` in `render` isn't actually a connected component.

According to the docs on `connect` (https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect):

> It does not modify the component class passed to it; instead, it returns a new, connected component class that wraps the component you passed in.

This means that simply calling `connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Counter);` will not mutate `Counter`, but it'll instead return a connected version of it instead. This returned component is what you want.

A quick fix to this would be to save `connect`'s return value:

```
const ConnectedCounter = connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

and use ConnectedCounter instead of Counter in render:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedCounter count={0}/>
</Provider>
```

---

When connecting components to the store, I suggest implementing the component in its own `jsx` file and export the connected component as default.

In `Counter.jsx`, we can have...

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Counter = props => {
  console.log('>>> counter', props)
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>counter (Redux Version)</h1>
          <p>count: {props.count}</p>
      </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('>>> map state to props', state);
  return { count: state.counterReducer.count };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

...so whenever `Counter` is imported somewhere else in the project (`import Counter from '<path>/Counter'`), we're sure that `Counter` is already a connected component.